Django Admin Import Error: NOT NULL Constraint Failed for ForeignKey Field in CSV Import
I'm experiencing a persistent issue with importing CSV data into my Django project using the django-import-export library in the admin panel. When trying to import records for a Copy model which has ForeignKey relations, I keep encountering a NOT NULL constraint failed error for the book_id field.  AGAIN THIS ONLY OCCURS IN THE ADMIN PANEL, I have tested in shell and it works.  I am sure there is no issue with the CSV and likely not even the resources/models files.  It seems something is going wrong with the admin logic before the actual import.
Error looks like this but for every single row. It occurs when hitting "submit".  I never even get to "Confirm Import" button
Line number: 1 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 2 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 3 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 4 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 5 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 6 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 7 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 8 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 9 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id
Line number: 10 - NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_copy.book_id

Here are the relevant parts of my code:
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class Format(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Copy(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='copies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    format = models.ForeignKey(Format, related_name='copies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)


resources.py
from import_export import resources
from .models import Copy

class CopyResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Copy
        fields = ('id', 'book', 'format', 'location', 'is_available')
        import_id_fields = ['id']

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        book_title = row.get('Book Title')
        isbn = row.get('ISBN')
        author = row.get('Author')
        format_name = row.get('Format')
        
        book, created = Book.objects.get_or_create(
            title=book_title,
            defaults={'isbn': isbn, 'author': author}
        )
        format, created = Format.objects.get_or_create(
            name=format_name
        )

        row['book'] = book.pk
        row['format'] = format.pk


admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from .models import Copy
from .resources import CopyResource

class CopyAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CopyResource

admin.site.register(Copy, CopyAdmin)


I've manually verified the CSV and even tested uploading in the django shell which worked properly.  But admin panel still does not work!!!
        import tablib
   ...: from catalog.resources import CopyResource
   ...: 
   ...: with open('library_copies.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   ...:     data = tablib.Dataset().load(f.read(), format='csv')
   ...: 
   ...: resource = CopyResource()
   ...: result = resource.import_data(data, dry_run=False)
   ...: 
   ...: if result.has_errors():
   ...:     print("Errors occurred during the import:")
   ...:     for error in result.base_errors:
   ...:         print(f"Base error: {error.error}")
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("The import would proceed without errors.")

The above succeeds but import through admin panel always has NOT NULL error
Edit: Adding logs for manual shell run vs admin panel.  It leads me to believe the CopyResource logic is not being used at all in the admin panel, and I cannot figure out why.  It says Resource: CopyResource in the admin panel, but it does not follow the proper logic like in shell.
shell:
0.000) BEGIN; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x6"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x6"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x7"; args=None; alias=default
Before importing row... OrderedDict({'id': '1', 'Book Title': 'Thank You for My Service ', 'ISBN': '9781524796501', 'Author': 'Mat Best', 'Format': 'Large Print', 'Location': 'Juliefurt', 'Is Available': 'True'})
Row data: OrderedDict({'id': '1', 'Book Title': 'Thank You for My Service ', 'ISBN': '9781524796501', 'Author': 'Mat Best', 'Format': 'Large Print', 'Location': 'Juliefurt', 'Is Available': 'True'})
(0.000) SELECT "catalog_book"."id", "catalog_book"."title", "catalog_book"."author", "catalog_book"."isbn" FROM "catalog_book" WHERE "catalog_book"."title" = 'Thank You for My Service ' LIMIT 21; args=('Thank You for My Service ',); alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x8"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) INSERT INTO "catalog_book" ("title", "author", "isbn") VALUES ('Thank You for My Service ', 'Mat Best', '9781524796501') RETURNING "catalog_book"."id"; args=('Thank You for My Service ', 'Mat Best', '9781524796501'); alias=default
(0.000) ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x8"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x8"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x7"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s8585724224_x9"; args=None; alias=default
Before importing row... OrderedDict({'id': '2', 'Book Title': 'Thank You for My Service ', 'ISBN': '9781524796501', 'Author': 'Mat Best', 'Format': 'Large Print', 'Location': 'Hernandezport', 'Is Available': 'True'})

admin panel:
(0.000) BEGIN; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s6196490240_x1"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s6196490240_x1"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s6196490240_x2"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "catalog_copy"."id", "catalog_copy"."book_id", "catalog_copy"."format_id", "catalog_copy"."location", "catalog_copy"."is_available" FROM "catalog_copy" WHERE "catalog_copy"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 21; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) INSERT INTO "catalog_copy" ("book_id", "format_id", "location", "is_available") VALUES (NULL, NULL, '', 1) RETURNING "catalog_copy"."id"; args=(None, None, '', True); alias=default
(0.000) ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT "s6196490240_x2"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s6196490240_x2"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SAVEPOINT "s6196490240_x3"; args=None; alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "catalog_copy"."id", "catalog_copy"."book_id", "catalog_copy"."format_id", "catalog_copy"."location", "catalog_copy"."is_available" FROM "catalog_copy" WHERE "catalog_copy"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 21; args=(); alias=default



which version of django-import-export are you using?

@MatthewHegarty Thank you for helping!!!
Name: django-import-export
Version: 4.0.0

I suggest trying in 3.3.8 just to see if it is a regression in v4

@MatthewHegarty , It worked!!!! You are a gentleman and a scholar
